# Установить стандарт языка C++ в Visual Studio 2022

Tags: c++, visual-studio, c++20

С любыми проектами, где есть .vcxproj, проблем не возникает: ПКМ на проекте -> свойства -> язык -> стандарт.

НО когда мой проект это папка, в которой лежат ресурсы, папки с хедерами и исходниками и 3 конфига для CMake, нужной кнопки в обозревателе решений нет. (Я открываю проект через проводник, нажимаю пкм -> "Открыть с помощью Visual Studio")

Подскажите, как в таких случаях изменить стандарт языка, возможно это можно сделать через строку команд в VS или как-то еще...

Если нажать ПКМ на корневую папку проекта, окно свойств будет пустым. Переключиться в окно свойств проекта через компоненты поиска тоже не получается.
По умолчанию в Visual Studio 2022 стоит 14 стандарт, мне нужен 20.

Comment: Очевидно, язык задается в "3 конфига для CMake".

Comment: Судя по всему проблема в другом. Почему-то ide подчеркивает std::views::filter, но не подчеркивает std::views::transform, хотя они были добавлены одновременно в 20 стандарте. Почему может быть так?

Comment: `set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 20)` в `CMakeLists.txt`